# How to “upsert” multiple records at once with Vapor 3 / PostgresSQL

Tags: swift, postgresql, fluent, vapor

I have this insert:

```
conn.insert(into: MyModel.self).values(rates).run()
```

Where `MyModel` conforms to `PostgreSQLModel` and `rates` is `[MyModel]`. I cannot grok the syntax for upsert which I have found solutions to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54408370/6444) in the context of inserting multiple rows.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: As FYI... Some time age, I looked for an `upsert` capability via SQLite flavor of Fluent. At that time, the Fluent `save(on: connection)` did not actually provide an `upsert` feature. See https://github.com/vapor/fluent-sqlite-driver/issues/23 Just added a Fluent "Feature Request: SQL MERGE (aka UPSERT) capability" here https://github.com/vapor/fluent/issues/640